# Windows Schedule Task continues to run after task completes

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, sftp, winscp

I have a windows scheduled task on a Windows 2012 R2 server that runs a `.bat` file that executes the following

```
cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
WinSCP /script="C:\Users\Administrator\AI_SFTP_Download\SFTP_Download.txt" /log="C:\Users\Administrator\AI_SFTP_Download\winscp.log"
exit /b
```

This is my SFTP_Download.txt script

```
# Connect
open "xxxxxxxx" -hostkey="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary
# Download file to the local directory d:\
get 211_AI_DR.zip.pgp D:\AIFiles\
# Disconnect
close
```

At the end of the log file I see that the process is completing

```
< 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 30, Number: 5771525
. 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Preserving timestamp [2015-12-22T09:32:48.000Z]
. 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Transfer done: '/Home/Brokers Service Marketing Group/211_AI_DR.zip.pgp' [807259773]
> 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Script: close
. 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Closing connection.
. 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Sending special code: 12
. 2015-12-22 09:47:48.893 Sent EOF message
```

Comment: Would have to see how the task is configured.  But instead of the last two commands I would change how you are starting WinSCP to: `START "" WinSCP /script="D:\AIFiles\SFTP_Download.txt"`

Comment: it can be that you need "exit /b" . Just a guess though.

Comment: It would be dangerous to execute the `taskkill` because it would kill all `cmd` tasks, not just this particular one. You say "the task is still running" - is `winscp` still running, or has `winscp` stopped and exited?

Comment: The first line must be with quotes around path containing spaces and parentheses, and using option `/D` is also always a good idea, i.e. `cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"`. However, if `WinSCP.exe` should download files, it is most likely much better to set as current directory a folder usually not write protected like the program files directory. Better set a current directory with write permissions for everyone and run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"` with full path, best using command __start__ as suggested by [Squashman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman).

Comment: @Squashman How does the `start` help? If the problem is that the WinSCP does not finish, you only hide away the problem by starting WinSCP asynchronously. The Scheduler task will finish, but WinSCP will still keep running in the background. That's not a solution.

Comment: @steveman2292 Add `/log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log` to WinSCP command-line and show us the log + Show us the `SFTP_Download.txt`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl that is what I was trying to determine as well. Is winscp the problem or is the task configured incorrectly.

Comment: @Squashman the path that the task is downloading to is on a different drive, that is just where the WinSCP.exe is located.

Comment: @Magoo the WinSCP task finishes, and the file downloads successfully, but the windows task continues to say "Running"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction everybody, I was able to solved the issue by adding the `exit` into the `SFTP_Download.txt` script.

Comment: It's just `exit`, not `exit /b`.

Comment: thank you, i just assumed that the /b would also be required